# phpMyAdmin and SHOW CREATE TABLE

Tags: phpmyadmin, shortcut, create-table

Is there a shortcut in phpMyAdmin to `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for a table (i.e. a button I can click to get the full query, not the truncated one)?

Also, can I query multiple `SHOW CREATE TABLE`s simultaneously in phpMyAdmin? If I separate them, only the last one appears.

Answer (score 23):

If you are trying to export the Table Schema Using the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` Query Inside **phpmyadmin**, and are getting some **truncated SQL** then please follow the following steps to output the complete `SQL Query` to replicate the table structure.

- There is this Hyperlink named `+Options` right above the truncated SQL that you are getting, Clicking on which shall make make a few toggles/options appear.
- There select `Full Texts`, And right below this toggle there is this `Go` button, maybe on the extreme right.
- And You should get the Full Text of the SQL.

Answer (score 17):

Click the database > Select the tables you want > Choose `With selected: Show create` > done

Screenshots:

[image: Click the database]

[image: Select the tables you want > Choose With selected: Show create]

[image: done]

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like what you want is all/part of the result of the 'export' tab.

If you tell it to export in sql, it gives you the table creation and popluation code (for all tables in the database)